# Angular - show loading icon depends on $http.pendingRequests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, angular-ui-router

I'm working on loading icon which ideally I would be able to display it whenever  *$http.pendingRequests* is not equal to zero and also old state is not equal to new one (I use *Angular Ui-Router*). Here is my code :

**master.blade.php:**

```
.
.
.
<div class="loading-burger-holder" data-loading>
    <div class="burger-overlay"></div>
    <div class="burger-loader">
        <img src="/app/user/assets/img/img-ico/loader.gif" class="img-responsive">
        <p>plaese wait ...</p>
    </div>
</div>
.
.
.
```

**clientGateway.js:**

```
.
.
.

$rootScope.isLoading = function () {
    console.log($http.pendingRequests.length  ,"length");
    return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
};

var state = '-';
$rootScope.$watch($rootScope.isLoading, function (v) {
    if (v && state != $state.current.name) {
        $('.loading-burger-holder').show();
    } else {
        state = $state.current.name;

        $('.loading-burger-holder').hide();
    }
});
.
.
.
```

It doesn't work in all situation. Is any alternate solution would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use watch for this

```
<div ng-show="!isLoading()" class="burger-overlay"></div>
<div ng-show="isLoading()" class="burger-loader">
    <img src="/app/user/assets/img/img-ico/loader.gif" class="img-responsive">
    <p>plaese wait ...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If I did not use $watch , How can I recognize $state  is change?

Comment: i didn't see $state usage in your question but if you want to recognize $state changes you can use `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', `....